# Bigquery not creating table from csv file

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, unzip

Im trying to follow along the Coursera Data Analytics course. Instructions are to download this file [names.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMpEt.png) or https://storage.googleapis.com/gwg-content/gdac006/names.zip

I've tried the zipped and unzipped folder option. First image is zipped [zipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I0iv.png) Second image unzipped and with file needed 'yob2014.txt' [yob2014.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdOKl.png) I also placed 'yob2014.txt' in 'documents' by itself

This is what the files look like in file explorer
[zipped and unzipped folder look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5l9x.png)

When auto detect is not checked this is the response [auto detect unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV9Pq.png)

Thankful for any help! :)

This is what it should look like [results of created table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3rN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions weren't clear and after continuing to work on my question i found out that i needed to create "schemas" (sorry not sure if that's correct, but im attaching an image for you to see) [correct way to create table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYxKi.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).